# Data security concern with downloaded extensions of Qlik sense

Tags: security, data-visualization, business-intelligence, qliksense

I'm using qlik sense and love it, I have also been using some nice extensions which downloaded from internet.
Today, I tried https://www.vizlib.com/protected/downloads , it looks good, but somehow it checked & have the user log-ins on my Qlik server to check the licenses. It raised me a concern that if the downloaded extensions of qlik sense are secure, my data, information on Qlik app might be at risk with those extensions.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe this is not related to programming at all.

Comment: yes, it's not related to programming, you can see there is no tag for any programming language? This question is for qlik sense and data visualization.

Comment: @kidgu For this purpose (being sure that a custom visualization extension in Qlik Sense follows best practices and doesn't do any harmful things), the TED (Trusted Extension Developer Program) was started by Qlik.
If an extension is trusted, then it has gone trough extensive manual and automated review by Qlik.
See more details details here: https://developer.qlik.com/ted

Comment: So, the exceptions which available on Qlik Branch are supposed to be under TED?  Correct? @StefanWalther . Thanks so much for your information

Comment: @kidgu, sorry to say, extensions being listed on Qlik Branch are not automatically under TED ... typically extensions being accredited use the TED stamp.
You'll then find most of them on https://market.qlik.com/solutions?TED

Comment: quite shock for this information, thank you anyway,@StefanWalther